# More expensive token everyday

Tags: solidity, price

I'm using a very simple crowdsale it just sells tokens in ratio 1ETH=10000 tokens

I would like to change this so every day token would be more expensive for example

Day1: 1ETH = 10 000 Tokens
Day2: 1ETH = 9 950 Tokens
Day3: 1ETH = 9 900 Tokens

and so on...

heres the code i use now

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

interface token {
    function transfer(address receiver, uint amount) external;
}

contract Crowdsale {
    address public beneficiary;
    uint public amountRaised;
    uint public price;
    token public tokenReward;
    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;

    event FundTransfer(address backer, uint amount, bool isContribution);

    /**
     * Constructor function
     *
     * Setup the owner
     */
    constructor(
        address ifSuccessfulSendTo,
        uint milietherCostOfEachToken,
        address addressOfTokenUsedAsReward
    ) public {
        beneficiary = ifSuccessfulSendTo;
        price = milietherCostOfEachToken * 0.0001 ether;
        tokenReward = token(addressOfTokenUsedAsReward);
    }

    function () payable public {

        uint amount = msg.value;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += amount;
        amountRaised += amount;
        tokenReward.transfer(msg.sender, amount * 10**18 / price);
        emit FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, true);

        // Forward funds immediately to beneficiary
        beneficiary.transfer(amount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the crowdsale start in the constructor, like

```
uint crowdsaleStart;

constructor(
    address ifSuccessfulSendTo,
    uint milietherCostOfEachToken,
    address addressOfTokenUsedAsReward
) public {
    crowdsaleStart = now
    ...
}
```

and then, with [now](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=block#block-and-transaction-properties) special variable, use it to calculate how many tokens contributors should get for 1 ETH:

```
uint16 MAX_REWARD = 10000
uint16 MIN_REWARD = 1000

function () payable public {
    ...
    //uint16 should be enough, but check your types max values anyway
    uint16 daysPassed = (now - crowdsaleStart) / 60 / 60 / 24;

    //10k on the first day, 9950 on the second etc.
    uint16 tokensPerETH = MAX_REWARD - 50 * daysPassed;
    //make sure they get at least something
    tokensPerETH = tokensPerETH >= MIN_REWARD ? tokensPerETH : MIN_REWARD;
    //and make sure it's not too much, in case of underflow
    //best be sure it doesn't happen, or limit your daysPassed based price penalty
    tokensPerETH = tokensPerETH <= MAX_REWARD ? tokensPerETH : MAX_REWARD;

    //overflow isn't an issue here, nobody will send you zillions of ETH
    //but still it's a good idea to use OpenZeppelin's SafeMath
    reward = msg.value * tokensPerEth / 1 ether;

    tokenReward.transfer(msg.sender, reward);
    ...
}
```

or you can use `price` and change it in a similar way, use any "time to price" formula you like.

Check out [SafeMath by OpenZeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol), almost never hurts to use it when counting ETH and tokens.